# How would I find the length of a string using NASM?

Tags: linux, string, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to make a program using NASM that takes input from command line arguments. Since string length is not provided, I'm trying to make a function to compute my own. Here is my attempt, which takes a pointer to a string in the `ebx` register, and returns the length of the string in `ecx`:

```
len:
    push ebx
    mov ecx,0
    dec ebx
    count:
        inc ecx
        inc ebx
        cmp ebx,0
        jnz count
    dec ecx
    pop ebx
    ret
```

My method is to go through the string, character by character, and check if it's null. If it's not, I increment `ecx` and go to the next character. I believe the problem is that `cmp ebx,0` is incorrect for what I'm trying to do. How would I properly go about checking whether the character is null? Also, are there other things that I could be doing better?

Comment: `cmp ebx,0` is wrong and also the `push ebx` at the end should probably be `pop ebx` (otherwise you'll get a *stack overflow* !).

Comment: Oops. I mistakenly hand-copied `pop ebx` as `push ebx`.

Comment: try and get into the habit of copying and pasting your actual code, rather than re-typing it. Also please edit your question so that it matches the actual code.

Comment: @paul-r That's what I usually do. I was working in VirtualBox and clipboard sharing was not set up properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing the value in `ebx` with 0 which is not what you want. The value in `ebx` is the address of a character in memory so it should be dereferenced like this:

```
cmp byte[ebx], 0
```

Also, the last `push ebx` should be `pop ebx`.

Comment: Could you please share a fully working code with this example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it in a 64-bit Linux executable that checks `argv[1]`.  The kernel starts a new process with `argc` and `argv[]` on the stack, as documented in the x86-64 System V ABI.

```
_start:
    pop    rsi              ; number of arguments (argc)
    pop    rsi              ; argv[0] the command itself (or program name)
    pop    rsi              ; rsi = argv[1], a pointer to a string
    mov    ecx, 0           ; counter
.repeat:
    lodsb                   ; byte in AL
    test   al,al            ; check if zero
    jz     .done            ; if zero then we're done
    inc    ecx              ; increment counter
    jmp    .repeat          ; repeat until zero
.done:
    ; string is unchanged, ecx contains the length of the string


; unused, we look at command line args instead
section .rodata
    asciiz:    db    "This is a string with 36 characters.", 0
```

This is slow and inefficient, but easy to understand.

For efficiency, you'd want

- only 1 branch in the loop ([Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump))
- avoid a false dependency by loading with `movzx` instead of merging into the previous RAX value ([Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)).
- subtract pointers after the loop instead of incrementing a counter inside.

And of course SSE2 is always available in x86-64, so we should use that to check in chunks of 16 bytes (after reaching an alignment boundary).  See optimized hand-written `strlen` implementations like in glibc.  (https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here how I would have coded it

```
len:
      push ebx
      mov  eax, ebx
lp:
        cmp byte [eax], 0
        jz  lpend
        inc eax
        jmp lp
lpend:
        sub eax, ebx

      pop ebx
      ret
```

(The result is in eax). Likely there are better ways.

Comment: Pointer-increment is better, but the terrible loop structure is a bottleneck on many CPUs.  You have 2 branches (one taken, one not-taken) in each loop iteration, so it can only run at one iteration per 2 clocks on CPUs before Haswell, i.e. ones that existed when you wrote this.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926).  (Of course only checking one byte at a time is pretty terrible for modern x86 with SSE2.)